# I have to press "Run" twice or clean project before "Run" on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So, I'm quite new to Android Studio but I have an issue:
I program in Kotlin and when I change something in my code and press "Run" it just runs as it did before and ignoring the changes. If i press "Run" after that first try again it applies the changes.
It also works, if I first hit "Buld/Clean Project".

What am I doing wrong? How can I make Android Studio to take the new code immediately?

Cheers.

Comment: so i found a solution but it is not perfect. If I go to Run/Debug configuration, I can add a "Run Gradle task" (down at "Before launch") with "clean build" typed in Tasks.
Then it work but it always takes over a minute to compile...

Comment: having same issue after update

Comment: I have collected several related issues from IssueTracker, - https://issuetracker.google.com/177757643 'Run' button causes proper rebuilding and deploy of an app, but restarts an old version of it.
- https://issuetracker.google.com/173912349 Builds are not installed on device
- https://issuetracker.google.com/173209141 Application not killed after install
- https://issuetracker.google.com/177921108 Android Studio launches old version of app I am trying to upgrade to 4.1.3 to see if this issue has been fixed

Comment: Same issue on newer version of android studio 4.1.1.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### **Update**

it seems to be that the issue is fixed in newer android studio version, currently i am working on android studio 4.2.1 and it is working fine even with allowing the parallel run feature.

### Old Answer

After a long search, I found that the issue is in something called instant run when you rerun your code, to solve this issue in the older android studio you have to disable instant run by going to:

```
File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run
```

and then disable it.

For me I am using the android studio +4.0.0 version so I opened:

```
Run -> Edit configurations... -> disable check box (Allow parallel run)*
```

It may slow your build a little but it better than running the app more than one time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's so disturbing

Comment: Thank you so much. It was so annoying

Comment: I mage an issue in the bug tracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177757643

Comment: What are instant run and parallel run meant for?

Comment: Has it already been fixed in Android Studio 4.2.1?

Comment: i think so , after the last update i made i returend the default configuration and it works fine now

Comment: 4.2.2 still happening....